# Tool to draw the whole information flow architecture from source systems through a data warehouse up to data mart for BI and analytical needs

Tags: database, reporting, business-intelligence

I'm working for IT company that maintains multiple complex separate systems with own transactional databases.
We're working on BI platform that uses data from all these systems and I'm looking for tool that may help in drawing the whole information flow from source systems through a data warehouse up to data mart for BI and analytical needs.

There are hundreds of tables that I'm trying to map on data mart tables in data warehouse and then map the data marts on particular reports just to have overall plan for my team how it should be built. Ideally I want to add comments, codes and other notes that describe relations and requirements for particular objects like databases, tables or reports.

I may not have sufficient knowledge of overall standards in industry so if there is any please let me know. Database diagrams are almost ok but I don't need to draw database keys and relations.I need business dependencies between objects.

Thank you for your time!

[image]